# PHP prevent instantiation of standard class

Tags: php, class, instantiation

(*this is just theoretical question, and is not intended to server as a good example*)

lets say I write some kind of orm and all developers should use this class, is it possible to disallow the instantiation of certain std class in php, to make sure not other connection will be establish to this db?

E.g mysqli should not be able to be constructed.

Is this technical possible?

Thanks

Comment: Put it in the style guide. Peer reviews should be enough.

Comment: yes sure, but from a technical perspective, is this possible?

Comment: Basically no, if your code can instantiate a class, then any code can instantiate that class.... there is no way of limiting instantiation of a class to a specific library, especially when that class is a standard PHP class.... look at how Doctrine or Propel or Eloquent don't do it

Comment: Let me see if I understood. You want to prevent everyone from constructing `mysqli` objects just to prevent them from connecting to your db?

Comment: PHP7 introduced Anonymous Classes, which you can control access to, and limit so that only your library can create a particular Anonymous Class, but you can't prevent access to standard PHP classes

Comment: If it's your own class, or at least a class you have somehow modified, you could track it in a variable and in that way block its creation. Other possibilities include checking the caller and only allow the class to be instantiated by certain other classes and methods. For the built-in classes like MySQLi, that would probably be a bit harder and you might have to modify the module itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## There are several ways

... but none of it is perfect.

#### The easy way

If you don't want anyone to instanciate `mysql/i`, `mongodb`or the likes, you can simply unload the extension. Your ORM would need to use another connection class, then.

#### The hackish way

There's this nice extension called [runkit](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) which contains all the functions you should never use. It's possible to remove methods from classes so you might be able to overwrite the constructor of the class you wish to block. Do I need to mention that this is a *really* bad idea?

### The good way

... are code reviews. You might think that those aren't really preventing someone from using `mysqli`, but:

- You don't need to be doing worse things than your peers would do by circumventing the ORM.
- You know who tried it and are able to explain to them why they shouldn't do this.
- You're actually able to use the class. You might think now you never need it, but maybe your emergency logger shouldn't depend on your ORM. Oh, and by the way, your ORM needs to use it, too.

### TL;DR

Properly review your code. It's part of a good coding style anyway, prevents bad solutions to force good solutions and allows exceptions if required.

Comment: I was searching for some of this hacky ways, I'm not going to implement this somewhere, it is just for my personal knowledge and digging deeper into question related to php, thanks a lod

Comment: @ChristophHa Sometimes you need crazy solutions, but most of the time they're a bad idea. In case someone finds this via google, he should be warned. So np (;

Comment: yep, you are right, updated the question regarding to this